# Python3 cannot find statsmodels.api but I can and so can my linter

Tags: pip, python-3.6, statsmodels

I recently got into development with Python running on WSL (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

I followed the documentation from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote-tutorials/wsl/install-python) and I'm able to run simple python scripts.

I started playing around with libraries that I installed using the `pip3` command such as `numpy` and `pandas` and these work fine.

The problem arises when I try to use the `statsmodels` package.
I've installed it using `pip3 install statsmodels`

I can see the package in `/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels` I can even see the `api.py` file in that directory, however, when I type `import statsmodels.api as sm` as recommended on the [statsmodels website](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/gettingstarted.html) I get:

[image: error]

Console output:

```
username@DESKTOP-1JP4BIE:/mnt/c/users/username/dev/project/playground$ python3 statsmodels.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "statsmodels.py", line 5, in <module>
    import statsmodels.api as sm
  File "/mnt/c/username/chris/dev/project/playground/statsmodels.py", line 5, in <module>
    import statsmodels.api as sm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels.api'; 'statsmodels' is not a package
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling (did not work)

I really can't see anything that differentiates this package from the others that I've installed. Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: The issue is that you have a file called `statsmodels.py` which your interpreter is using to find `api` within. Simply rename your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Vorsprung durch Technik

The issue was that my file name was statsmodels.py.

I'll remember to be more careful when naming my python files.